# ppx コマンドの簡単な呼び方を教えてください

Tags: ocaml

OCaml で ppx コマンドを呼び出す際に

```
ocaml -ppx `ocamlfind printconf path`/ppx_test/ppx_test
```

として ppx コマンドを指定しているのですが、より良い方法はありませんか？

※ 環境は Mac OS X です。ppx は OPAM からインストールしています。

#### 追記

```
$ ocamlfind ocaml -package ppx_test
```

または、

```
$ ocamlfind ocaml -package ppx_test/ppx_test
```

と入力したのですが以下のように表示されてしまいます。

```
Usage: ocamlfind query [-help | other options] ...
or: ocamlfind ocamlc [-help | other options] ...
or: ocamlfind ocamlcp [-help | other options] ...
or: ocamlfind ocamlmklib [-help | other options] ...
or: ocamlfind ocamlmktop [-help | other options] ...
or: ocamlfind ocamlopt [-help | other options] ...
or: ocamlfind ocamloptp [-help | other options] ...
or: ocamlfind ocamldep [-help | other options] ...
or: ocamlfind ocamlbrowser [-help | other options]
or: ocamlfind ocamldoc [-help | other options] ...
or: ocamlfind install [-help | other options] ...
or: ocamlfind remove [-help | other options] 
or: ocamlfind printconf [-help] [variable]
or: ocamlfind list
or: ocamlfind pkg/cmd arg ...
Select toolchain with:
ocamlfind -toolchain 
Abbreviations:
e.g. ocamlfind opt instead of ocamlfind ocamlopt
```

`opam list` で見ると、ocamlfind のバージョンは

ocamlfind 1.5.5 A library manager for OCaml

です。Mac OS X で対応していない、あるいは、ocamlfind のバージョンが古いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ppx コマンドは ocamlfind の `-package` オプションで簡単に呼び出すことができます:

```
ocamlfind ocamlc -package パッケージ名
```

と指定すると、 ocamlfind はコンパイルコマンド `-ppx ppxコマンドの絶対パス` を付けて実行します。

ただしこれには条件があって、 ppx コマンドが ocamlfind パッケージとして「正しく」インストールされている必要があります

- ppx コマンドが `ocamlfind query パッケージ` のディレクトリにインストールされていること
- パッケージの `META` ファイル中に `ppx=./コマンド名` という情報があること

`ppx` フィールどの値は `./` で始まっていない場合、パス展開は行われません。特段の事情がない限り `./` のない `ppx` フィールドは不便なだけなのでそのような `META` を配っているパッケージにはバグレポートするのが良いと思います。

### toplevel について

`ocaml` toplevel については `ocamlfind ocaml` というラップ自体が無いので、上の方法は使えません。（これは、なぜだか正直私にはわかりませんが）次のように toplevel から手でロードします

```
ocaml
# #use "topfind";;
# #require "ppx_test";;   (* ppx を含むパッケージのロード *)
```

この結果

```
絶対パス/./ppx_test: activated
```

と出ると ppx が使用されるようロードされた状態になります:

```
# _with_location_ 4;;
- : int * Ppx_test.Location.t =
(4,
 {Ppx_test.Location.loc_start =
   {Lexing.pos_fname = "//toplevel//"; pos_lnum = 1; pos_bol = 0;
    pos_cnum = 16};
  loc_end =
   {Lexing.pos_fname = "//toplevel//"; pos_lnum = 1; pos_bol = 0;
    pos_cnum = 17};
  loc_ghost = false})
```

繰り返し使う場合は ocamlinit ( http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual023.html )を使うことになります。

よりくわしくは findlib のマニュアルで ppx を検索してご覧ください http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/findlib-1.5.5/doc/ref-html/r700.html